# Angular Power Bi integration CORS problem

Tags: angular, api, http, powerbi, cors

everyone.

I've been trying for days to POST-call this Microsoft Power Bi's endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token which generates an access_token.

If called from Postman it returns a 200 OK like it's supposed to, plus the access_token I need to later call another endpoint (https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken) for the embed_token, which also works in Postman.

The problem is that the ouath2/token endpoint always returns
[ERR_FAILED 400 with a CORS error on top of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gvBZ.png).

I seriously don't know what I'm doing wrong. I feel like the Request Headers and Body are the way they are supposed to be, since they look the same in Postman and Angular.

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxido.png), I even tried to cleanse the HttpClient with fresh new headers not attached to our current solution/boilerplate (we use ASP.NET Zero), but still the same issue remains.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

To understand why the CORS problem only occurs in the browser we need to know what CORS is and how it is used in browsers.
From the [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) page from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins (domain, scheme, or port) other than its own from which a browser should permit loading resources. For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from scripts.This means that a web application using those APIs can only request resources from the same origin the application was loaded from unless the response from other origins includes the right CORS headers.

So there is no way for us to fix the CORS error because the server has to send these headers.

Since you only mentioned the `/oauth2/token` token endpoint, there is a high chance that the wrong OAuth grant type is being used. For Single Page Application (SPA) the OAuth 2.0 authorization code + PKCE flow is recommended. This one does not use a client secret.

For more information see the [Single-page apps (JavaScript)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-app-types#single-page-apps-javascript) on the Application types for the Microsoft identity platform in the Microsoft documentatation

Simply explained, your application redirects the user to the authorize page (`/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`). There the user logs in and is redirected back to the Angular application with a code. This code can then be used to retrieve the access token via the token endpoint (`/oauth2/v2.0/token`).